# Upgrading from RSpec 2.11 to 2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm upgrading RSpec and having problems with 2 elements in particular.  I'm [following this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#top) and, specifically, I'm having trouble with the method

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit root_path
  fill_in "Email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

where I get an error

```
undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x79b9c90>
```

Additionally I have another error

```
before {put user_path(user)}
```

gives

```
undefined method `put' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_3:0x7939830>
```

For the first, error, I was trying to follow the [steps in the RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/cookies) but I can't seem to figure out how to get an RSpec response object from a Capybara page (the result of calling `click_button`).  For the second error, I'm really at a loss.  It looks like RSpec just removed the `put` function, and I don't know how to get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an RSpec problem, rather an Request/Integration vs Functional/Controller spec issue.

Capybara, or more specifically 'request' or 'integration' specs do not provide access to the request methods like put() or get() - these are only in controller specs that live specs/controllers/. The same with the cookies[] hash and [other variables available](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-four-hashes-of-the-apocalypse) when you are testing the controllers directly.

[See this gist](https://gist.github.com/484787) for a work-around.

Comment: I just tried to create a new spec in spec/controllers with just the put method described above, and now I'm getting an error saying user_path isn't available.  Any idea how to merge the two?  Also when did this change?  It worked in the previous version of RSpec and Capybara.